# How to call a specific Google Cloud Function?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm currently deploying a few files that contain multiple functions as well as JavaScript frameworks to Google Cloud Function like this:

```
./google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud functions deploy newFunc --trigger-http --source=/Users/dir --entry-point=myFunction
```

This creates one entry named "newFunc" on the Google Cloud Platform which can be accessed through "https://someurl.cloudfunctions.net/newFunc". This URL only calls one of the functions in the file.

How do I call other functions? Do I have to deploy each function with a different name? If so, do I have to deploy frameworks each time along with package.json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each function that you want to call from the public Internet, you must create a new Cloud Function and use that service's URL. Each public function is unique.

Functions (methods) internal to a Cloud Function cannot be called in addition to the main entry point from the Internet.

Comment: If all the functions share a common framework from NPM, do I have to deploy the framework and package.json for each function?

Comment: Yes. Cloud Functions are independent of each other. Another option to consider is to use Google Cloud Run which will provide you with the [domainname]/path?query style of naming internal functions. You could deploy one Cloud Run service for all of your endpoints.